# Android: java.util.logging.Logger vs android.util.Log

Tags: java, android, logging

Why does `Android` maintain 2 different Log classes that seem to support the same things?

I'm talking about:

1. `Log` [android.util.Log](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html)
2. `Logger` [java.util.logging.Logger](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/logging/Logger.html)

For what I've seen for some years developing, every Android official documentation points to the `Log` and not the Logger.

Even specific loggers like the [TimingLogger](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TimingLogger.html) uses the `Log`.

---

**So why are those 2 supported?**

Are there any feature that can be used through `Logger` than I can't achieve through `Log`?

Are there specific use cases for both?

Answer (score 3):

The feature crossover seems to be:

1. [android.util.Log](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) = [java.util.logging.Logger](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/logging/Logger.html)
2. [android.util.Printer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Printer.html) = [java.util.logging.Formatter](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/logging/Formatter.html)
3. [android.util.PrintStreamPrinter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/PrintStreamPrinter.html) = [java.util.logging.StreamHandler](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/logging/StreamHandler.html)

Seems like "android.util.Log" is going to have:

1. Support for [android log](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LogPrinter.html).
2. Support for out to Streams, Writers, and Strings.
3. Is going to be a smaller, lightweight, and probably faster.

Looks like "J.U.L" is going to have:

1. Buffering of records with the [java.util.logging.MemoryHandler](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/logging/MemoryHandler.html).  This is good for say when a `SEVERE` error occurs you can include the last 1000 records which may be at lower level.
2. Filtering of records using [java.util.logging.Filter](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/logging/Filter.html).  There are no out of box filters included but it does give more granularity over implementing this behavior in a [android.util.Printer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Printer.html)
3. Out of box support for [XML](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/logging/XMLFormatter.html).
4. Out of box support for [Sockets](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/logging/SocketHandler.html).
5. Support for 3rd party [java.util.logging.Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/logging/Handler.html) implementations.